# Receber dois números, somar os pares e multiplicar os ímpares

Tags: python, lista, for

O programa deve receber dois números, e então some todos os pares entre o intervalo recebido, e multiplicar todos os ímpares do intervalo recebido (incluindo os digitados, sempre).

Deve ser usado `for` ou `while`

Como apresentar o resultado?

Por exemplo, imaginando que o usuário informou os valores 2 e 8, então a saída seria:

```
2 + 4 + 6 + 8 -> 20

3 * 5 * 7 -> 105
```

Meu código segue abaixo:

```
numero = 0
contador = 1

for numero in range(numero, 3, 2):
    numero = int(input(f'Informe um número {contador}/2: '))
    contador = contador + 1
while numero % 2 == 0:
    for numero in range(numero, numero + numero):
        print(numero)
while numero % 2 != 0:
    for numero in range(numero, numero * numero):
        print(numero)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usuário insere o valor de começo e de fim:

```
valor1 = int(input())
valor2 = int(input())
```

Armazena a soma dos pares e a multiplicação dos impares:

```
par = 0
impar = 1
```

Aqui o loop for itera sobre o valor inicial e o  final + 1:

```
for numero in range(valor1, valor2 + 1):
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        par += numero
    else:
        impar *= numero
```

Impressão dos valores:

```
print(f'par: {par}, impar: {impar}')
```

Comment: Obrigado. Deu certinho, e consegui entender. :)

Comment: EWSG, boa tarde! Por nada meu caro. Abraço!

Comment: @EWSG se foi essa a resposta que te ajudou, considere marcar como a correta para ajudar quem tiver a mesma dúvida que você no futuro. Veja a ["O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e ["Como e por que aceitar uma resposta"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Comment: Opa, pode deixar. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

A ideia é fazer uma função que retorne os valores, bem genérica.

```
 def somaParMultImpar(numero1,numero2):
     
     impar = 1
     par = 0
     while(numero1<=numero2):
         if(numero1%2 == 0):
           par+=numero1
         else:
            impar*=numero1
         numero1+=1
     return impar, par
print(somaParMultImpar(2,10))
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Acabei optando pelo código do colega acima, pois consegui compreendê-lo melhor. :)